# How to use DB Models to OO in Android?

Tags: android, object

I've seen this into C#, the guy developed the database model, so everytime he needed to use inserts os includes, he just reffers to that model. Is there something like this into android?
All i could think was into array builders, indo model classes, then call then.

Any other idea?

---

EDIT:
I want to have a class which is a model of a table from the database. So every time i call an insert, for example, it recall into the model class, knowning the fields the table haves. Just for OO purposes.

Comment: could you be more specific of what you're trying to do? That way others can post relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different Android ORMs that try and keep as minimal SQLite I/O exposed and just expose your own models.

Db4Objects - http://www.db4o.com/

ActiveAndroid - https://www.activeandroid.com/

Each has their own pros/cons so you will need to try out each. Google around, others have tried both and have notes of their own.

I tried each and at the time had bugs in ActiveAndroid. Db4Objects is pure OO so doesnt even use SQLite.

In the end I ended up going with ORMLite - http://ormlite.com/ as I found it the best fit for my needs